# Replace certain columns in a data frame with the columns of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames with the same columns names and the same size. Each of them has 40 columns and 5000 rows. I would like to replace certain columns in a data frame with those from the other df arranged by their common ID. The column ID is identical for both dfs but not necessarily in the same order for each df.
Let me provide an example for clarity.

```
  df1 <- data.frame( ID = c("ID1", "ID2","ID3", "ID4","ID5", "ID6","ID7", "ID8", "ID9"),
                  A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                  B = c(11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91),
                  C = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"),
                  D = c("a1","b1","c1", "d1","e1", "f1", "g1", "h1", "i1")
)
df1

df2 <- data.frame( ID = c("ID2", "ID1","ID3", "ID4","ID5", "ID6","ID9", "ID8", "ID7"),
                   A = sample(x = 1:20, size = 9), 
                   B = sample(x = 1:50, size = 9),
                   C = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),
                   D = c("A1","B1","C1", "D1","E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1")
)
 df2
```

This should be the df2 after replacing its columns, A, B with those from df1 while keeping the rest of the columns (C, D) unchanged.

```
df2_out <- data.frame( ID = c("ID2", "ID1","ID3", "ID4","ID5", "ID6","ID9", "ID8", "ID7"),
                   A = c(2,1,3,4,5,6,9,8,7), 
                   B = c(21,11,31,41,51,61,91,81,71),
                   C = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),
                   D = c("A1","B1","C1", "D1","E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1")
)
```

As mentioned the number of the columns to be changed is long (30) in my data set:
changed_columns <- c("A", "B", ....)

any help on how to make it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using the `data.table` package, you can solve your problem as follows:

```
  library(data.table)

  setDT(df2)[df1, c("A", "B") := .(i.A, i.B), on = "ID"]

  #     ID A  B C  D
  # 1: ID2 2 21 A A1
  # 2: ID1 1 11 B B1
  # 3: ID3 3 31 C C1
  # 4: ID4 4 41 D D1
  # 5: ID5 5 51 E E1
  # 6: ID6 6 61 F F1
  # 7: ID9 9 91 G G1
  # 8: ID8 8 81 H H1
  # 9: ID7 7 71 I I1
```

Comment: Putting setDT on a separate line would make this more readable to someone who doesn't know `data.table`, imo

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option by using `merge` + `subset`

```
df2_out <- subset(merge(df1[c("ID","A","B")],df2,all = TRUE,by = "ID"),select = -cbind(A.y,B.y))
```

such that

```
> df2_out
   ID A.x B.x C  D
1 ID1   1  11 B B1
2 ID2   2  21 A A1
3 ID3   3  31 C C1
4 ID4   4  41 D D1
5 ID5   5  51 E E1
6 ID6   6  61 F F1
7 ID7   7  71 I I1
8 ID8   8  81 H H1
9 ID9   9  91 G G1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` to get the order of `ID` and replace them with `changed_columns` in `df1`.

```
changed_columns <- c("A", "B")
df2[match(df1$ID, df2$ID), changed_columns] <- df1[changed_columns]

df2
#   ID A  B C  D
#1 ID2 2 21 A A1
#2 ID1 1 11 B B1
#3 ID3 3 31 C C1
#4 ID4 4 41 D D1
#5 ID5 5 51 E E1
#6 ID6 6 61 F F1
#7 ID9 9 91 G G1
#8 ID8 8 81 H H1
#9 ID7 7 71 I I1
```